# How can I use JWT token in DRF tests?

Tags: unit-testing, django-rest-framework, jwt

I need to test my API. For example, I have images list page. I need to do tests for this page, but I cannot do this without authentication. I use JWT. I do not know how to do it.
Help me please.

tests.py

```
class ImagesListTestCase(APITestCase):
    def test_images_list(self):
        response = self.client.get('/api/', HTTP_AUTHORIZATION="JWT {}".format("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkzNzUxMzMxLCJqdGkiOiI3NWE3NDNkMGU3MDQ0MGNiYjQ3NDExNjQ3MTI5NWVjNSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.7HkhZ1hRV8OtQJMMLEAVwUnJ0yDt8agFadAsJztFb6A"))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I tried to do

```
response = self.client.get('/api/', Authorization="Bearer <token>")
```

Also

```
response = self.client.get('/api/', Authorization="JWT <token>")

response = self.client.get('/api/', HTTP_AUTHORIZATION="Bearer <token>")
```

Comment: Get the JWT token first.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: Reading your api document to see the way to attach the token, and reading your http client document to see how to do that.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

django creates a temporary database for test; so it's better to get token from `username` and `password` like this:

```
class ImagesListTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self) :
    self.register_url = reverse("your:register:view")  # for example : "users:register"
    self.user_data = {
        "username": "test_user",
        "email": "test_user@gmail.com",
        "password": "123456"
    }
    self.client.post(self.register_url,self.user_data)      # user created

    auth_url = reverse("your:login:view") #for example :"users:token_obtain_pair"
    self.access_token = self.client.post(auth_url,{
        "username" : self.user_data.get("username") ,
        "password" : self.user_data.get("password")
    }).data.get("access")       # get access_token for authorization
    self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f'Bearer {self.access_token}')
    
    def test_images_list(self):
        response = self.client.get('/api/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create users that require JWT authentication like:

```
    def setUp(self) -> None:
    self.client = APIClient()

    if os.environ.get('GITHUB_WORKFLOW'):
        local_token_url = 'https://testing/app/token/jwt'
    else:
        local_token_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/token/jwt'

    response = requests.post(local_token_url, {'email': 'test_contact1@user.com', 'password': '123pass321'})
    self.test_user1 = json.loads(response.text)
    response = requests.post(local_token_url, {'email': 'test_contact2@user.com', 'password': '123pass321'})
    self.test_user2 = json.loads(response.text)

    self.contact_person = apm.AppUser.objects.create(email="test_contact1@user.com", first_name="John",
                                                     last_name="Doe",
                                                     company_name="test_company_1", phone_number="08077745673",
                                                     is_active=True)
```

you can then use them like below parsing data = {}

```
self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION="Bearer {}".format(self.test_user1.get('access')))
    response = self.client.post(reverse('create-list'), data=data, format='json')
    print(response.data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking api to get the token, Another very simple solution can as follows

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken

 def setUp(self):
    self.factory = APIRequestFactory() 
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='jacob', email='jacob@gmail.com', password='top_secret')
    self.client = APIClient()
    token = AccessToken.for_user(user=user)
    self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f'Bearer {token}')
```

and it will be used as

```
def test_get_cities(self):
    response = self.client.get('/<actual path to url>/cities/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(response.data) == 0
    self.assertEqual(response.data, [])
```

Important thing to notice here is in **setUp** function token is generated using AcessToken class from JWT itself, so no actual API is required for testing other flows in your app.